# Is the Silverlight downloads on Ubuntu safe to use (mokeke.sytes.com)

Tags: 14.04, moonlight

I would like to know whether the Silverlight alternatives available at (http://mokeke.sytes.net/downloads/linux/Novell_Moonlight/) is safe to use?

novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.crx for Chrome
novell-moonlight-3.99.0.3-x86_64.xpi for FF

Answer (score 0):

Moonlight has been unmaintained for sometime now.
If you need Silverlight functionality, consider using Pipelight - https://launchpad.net/pipelight

> Pipelight is a special browser plugin which allows one to use windows
>   only plugins inside Linux browsers. We are currently focusing on
>   Silverlight, Flash, Shockwave and the Unity Webplayer. The project
>   needs a patched version of Wine to execute the Silverlight DLL.

Installation details: http://fds-team.de/cms/pipelight-installation.html

Comment: Thanks. I agree, but the moonlight options seems so much easier. No wine etc.

Comment: Yes, but getting back to the original question: how *safe* is this? I'm uncomfortable installing anything remotely to do with Microsoft on my machine. Corporate software being allowed to rummage around my system is scary. What are the credentials for Pipelight, Moonlight, etc.?